# Bootstrap 4 navbar with dropdown menu but clickable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create menu with one bookmark with submenu, but I want to make a clickable bookmark which is drop-down button:

HOME

OFFER

- SHOP
- SERVICES

CONTACT

And I would like to open OFFER page and SHOP.

In bootstrap 4 documentation drop-down button shows submenu without possibility to click this bookmark (in my version is OFFER).

On PC we could use HOVER to create this, but on mobile it won't work, so how to do this?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what are you trying to accomplish...do you want to have Offer tab closed by default and open it on click event on mobile screen size?

Comment: Please add minimal working code

Comment: I would like to make navbar like this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#supported-content and here is DROPDOWN in menu and when you click it you shows submenu without possibility open this main page. I found something what works like I think it is the best way to solve my problem: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/#split-button 
here is split button, left side open page, but right side toggle submenu.
I tried to separate this for two <li>: https://codepen.io/SkuterPL/pen/RwbXgYe but on mobile bookmarks are one by one, but it should be next to one

Answer (score 0):

On the css side, you can make transactions with @media and show the menu in mobile dimensions.

I think this method can do your job.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
```

Comment: This is not what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

I added some code:
https://codepen.io/SkuterPL/pen/RwbXgYe

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown" style="">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Offer</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Offer menu"></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Shop</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Service</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This code works okey on PC, but not on mobile, because it creates new position in menu, so on mobile it create next bookmark to click instead of next to it